# How can I deal with rendering error of ListView in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, rendering

In my screen, I have a column and the column has a ListView and a textfield.
It's like a chat with a NPC, so if the users enter all of the answers, the textfield is changed into button.
At this point, rendering error is occurred and I don't know what the problem is.

Here is how it looks:

[image: What I'm doing in gif]

Partial code of my implementation is below.

```
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0,vertical: 30.0),
        itemCount: widgets.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index) => widgets[index],
        controller: _scrollController,
      ),
    ),
    state.showSubmitButton 
    ? Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
        child: PrimaryButton(
          color: primaryBeige,
          text: 'Submit',
          callback: ()=>_tagChatBloc.emitEvent(TagChatEventComplete())
        )
      ) 
    : (state.isDetailStoreLoading 
      ? Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
          child: CustomProgressIndicator()
        )
      : TagChatInput(scrollController: _scrollController)
    )
  ],
);
```

Error

> I/flutter (32685): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter (32685): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
>   I/flutter (32685): A RenderViewport exceeded its maximum number of layout cycles.
>   I/flutter (32685): RenderViewport render objects, during layout, can retry if either their slivers or their
>   I/flutter (32685): ViewportOffset decide that the offset should be corrected to take into account information collected
>   I/flutter (32685): during that layout.
>   I/flutter (32685): In the case of this RenderViewport object, however, this happened 10 times and still there was no
>   I/flutter (32685): consensus on the scroll offset. This usually indicates a bug. Specifically, it means that one of the
>   I/flutter (32685): following three problems is being experienced by the RenderViewport object:
>   I/flutter (32685):  * One of the RenderSliver children or the ViewportOffset have a bug such that they always think
>   I/flutter (32685):    that they need to correct the offset regardless.
>   I/flutter (32685):  * Some combination of the RenderSliver children and the ViewportOffset have a bad interaction such
>   I/flutter (32685):    that one applies a correction then another applies a reverse correction, leading to an infinite
>   I/flutter (32685):    loop of corrections.
>   I/flutter (32685):  * There is a pathological case that would eventually resolve, but it is so complicated that it
>   I/flutter (32685):    cannot be resolved in any reasonable number of layout passes.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: ListView must be wrap in size, use SizedBox or Container. ConstraintBox etc.

Comment: Hi, I've just updated your question to help it be a little easier to read, and to show the gif inline with the text instead of as a link.

Answer (score 7):

The flutter layout manager does not know how far to expand your listview because it's going on and on and never finding a stopping point.

Here are some steps to take to build a messaging UI:

1. Set your column mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.max
2. Put your list view in an Expanded widget with a Container in that. So you'll have:

   - Expanded

     - Container

       - ListView
3. Wrap your "Message box UI" in a fixed height container so that Expanded can have a place to stop and add that as the last child of your list with your above conditionals to do that.

At the end you should have

```
Column: MainAxisSize.max
  Expanded
    Container: No given size
      ListView
  Container: Fixed height (For Messages input UI and your button)
```

This produces a chat UI. It's how I very recently implemented the same interface. Make sure that your conditional replaces the child of the fixed container and not the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

Lower versions will throw this exception. In my flutter app, 1.1.5 failed, 1.5.4 succeed.

Or you can change the flutter source code in directory：`packages\flutter\lib\src\rendering\sliver_list.dart.`

Details are in the links below：

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29852